# Iterate through list objects to find object with matching property value

Tags: c#, list, loops, object

I have a list of objects (users) of a class (User). Now I try to retrieve the (unique) object that has a certain property value (for example string username = name). So what needs to be returned is the object, based on the value of its property.

There are several similar questions asked here, but none seem to return the object as a whole.

I've tried several methods including this one:

```
public User GetUser(string name)
{
    User currentUser;

    for(int i = 0; i < this.users.Count; i++)
    {
        if (users[i].GetName().Equals(name))
        {
            users[i] = currentUser;
        }
    };

    return currentUser;
}
```

A problem here is that currentUser is not accepted as a variable. What would be a better way to go about this?

**EDIT:**
As stated in the answers the quickest solution for this issue is using LINQ. Also it was pointed out that what I was trying can be done without using LINQ, as shown below:

```
public User GetUser(string name)
        {           
            User currentUser = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < this.users.Count; i++)
            {
                if (users[i].GetName().Equals(name))
                {
                    currentUser = users[i];
                }
            };

            return currentUser;
        }
```

In case there are several users for which GetName equals to name, this method will return the last such user.

Comment: This code should not even compile as you are using unassigned variable `currentUser`.

Comment: What do you mean with `return the full object`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that this might be a confusing way to put it. I meant for it to return the object and not only properties of it and edited the question.

Comment: Hopefully you were seeking a copy-and-paste solution because only 1 of **5** answers comes close to showing, let alone _explaining_, where the mistake is in your code. You have `users[i] = currentUser;` reversed.  Correct it to `currentUser = users[i];` and, since the compiler can't prove that the `for` and `if` blocks will ever be entered, initialize your result variable with `User currentUser = null;` and it should work. Note that if there were multiple elements of `users` for which `GetName()` was equal to `name` then at the end of the loop `currentUser` would contain the _last_ such user.

Comment: Thank you very much @LanceU.Matthews for your thorough explanation of how to improve my code. I tried it out, it works and I updated the question to include this solution as an alternative to using LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LINQ`:

```
public User GetUser(string name)
{
    return users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetName().Equals(name));
}
```

**Note**: if such a name does not exist, the default will be returned, the default for this case is`null`.

Answer (score 1):

```
//     is optional, if you want ignore case
// users[i].GetName().Equals(name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
public User? GetUser(string name)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < this.users.Count; i++)
        if (users[i].GetName().Equals(name))
            return users[i]; // early-return pattern
    return null; // returns null if no such user found
}
```

Dont forget to check for null in client code:

```
var user = GetUser("SomeUserName");
if(user is null) {
    // do some
}
```

And if you like to use linq:

```
public User? GetUser(string name) => users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.GetName().Equals(name));
```

Comment: @Miles why not? Check fixed answer

Comment: The issue here is that the compiler assumes not all code paths might return a value

Comment: @Miles sry, miss that. Check last update. Be careful with nullable types, check for null in client code.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to get what you want is to use LinQ

```cs
var user = users.Where(user => user.GetName() == name).First();
```

or shorter

```cs
var user = users.First(user => user.GetName() == name);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to do this

```
var user = users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.GetName().Equals(name));
```

Answer (score 1):

use the getter for username in the User object in place of GetName

```
public User GetUser(string name)
{
   return users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.GetName().Equals(name));
}
```